# unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x748b800

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.2

Good day everyone! I would just want to ask what is wrong with what I am doing. I am working with this for two days and yet I still can't make it. It says "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x748b800". 
What I am doing is parsing a json returned value. Below is the sample json returned value:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "John Patola",
         "id": "123444432"
      },
      {
         "name": "Joshua Valdez",
         "id": "22234567778"
      }
]
}
```

I want to store them in an array called
    `NSArray *storage`.
Below are my codes:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
[self.rData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection: (NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
[rData release];
[connection release];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
NSString *myVar = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:rData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
NSArray *storage =[[(NSDictionary *)myVar objectForKey:@"data"]retain]; // this line seems to be the error
NSLog(@"%i", [storage count]);
```

When I run this code, I got an error "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x748b800". Do you think that the line I've marked really gives error? How can I fix it? Thank you for your help in advance. ;-)

Comment: I suggest you stop whatever you are doing and go off and learn basic debugging techniques. You should look at how to set breakpoints, how to step through and examine code. Then you should read up about common errors such as "unrecognized selector sent to instance" and what they mean and how you can debug them.

Comment: `"unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x748b800".` is that all the crash log you can provide?

Comment: I corrected my answer, try it. It works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `JSON` kit in your project.

Declare a method in your `viewController.h` file

```
-(void)JsonParsing:(NSString *)string;
```

Then import

```
#import "SBJSON.h"
#import "JSON.h"
```

in your `viewController.m` file and

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.rData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection: (NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [rData release];
    [connection release];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
 {
    NSString *theXMLString = [[NSString alloc]initWithBytes:[self.rData mutableBytes] length:[self.rData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self JsonParsing:theXMLString];
 }
```

Then parse your string here -

```
-(void)JsonParsing:(NSString *)string
{
    SBJSON *jsonObject = [[SBJSON alloc]init];
    NSArray *dataArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    dataArray = [jsonObject objectWithString:string];
    NSLog(@"%d", [dataArray count]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
 -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

   NSError *error = nil;
   NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: rData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

   if (!jsonArray) {
      NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON data: %@", e);
   } else 
   {
      NSArray *arrValues = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"data"];
      for(NSDictionary *item in arrValues) {
      NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
   }
}
```